# Flutter: datasource error with video_thumbnail package

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm trying to follow the example from [the video_thumbnail plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) to generate a thumbnail for a video I've placed locally in my android emulator Download folder:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';

class VideoSelectPageListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoName;

  const VideoSelectPageListTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.videoName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoSelectPageListTileState createState() =>
      _VideoSelectPageListTileState();
}

class _VideoSelectPageListTileState extends State<VideoSelectPageListTile> {
  Future<Image> generateThumbnail(String videoName) async {

    
    final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
      video: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/my-video-file.mp4",
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      maxWidth: 128, // specify the width of the thumbnail, let the height auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
      quality: 25,
    );

    return Image.memory(uint8list);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Image>(
      future: generateThumbnail(widget.videoName),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(widget.videoName),
            trailing: snapshot.data,
          );
        } else {
          return Text("No image can be generated");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

For whatever reason it continues to just throw IllegalArgumentExceptions at line 77 in the MediaMetadataRetriever.java class on build:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55082/iYajbqTSHdQ=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation(27588): eglMakeCurrent: 0xebc126a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2a0f850)
D/eglCodecCommon(27588): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
D/ThumbnailPlugin(27588): buildThumbnailData( format:0, maxh:0, maxw:128, timeMs:0, quality:25 )
W/System.err(27588): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
W/System.err(27588):    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:77)
W/System.err(27588):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin.createVideoThumbnail(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:201)
W/System.err(27588):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin.buildThumbnailData(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:116)
W/System.err(27588):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin.access$100(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:37)
W/System.err(27588):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin$1.run(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:77)
W/System.err(27588):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(27588):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(27588):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
D/EGL_emulation(27588): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2a1a2a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2a0fad0)
```

Is there some error in my implementation here? I ran the example program at the package link without issue and without adding additional permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Would one of you know how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
You need permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` 
Step 1: Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to `AndroidManifest.xml` 
Step 2: Request permission with `permission_handler`

```
 Future<Image> generateThumbnail(String videoName) async {
 
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();
    ...
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';

class VideoSelectPageListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoName;

  const VideoSelectPageListTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.videoName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoSelectPageListTileState createState() =>
      _VideoSelectPageListTileState();
}

class _VideoSelectPageListTileState extends State<VideoSelectPageListTile> {
  Future<Image> generateThumbnail(String videoName) async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();

    final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
      video: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/my-video-file.mp4",
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      maxWidth:
          128, // specify the width of the thumbnail, let the height auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
      quality: 25,
    );

    return Image.memory(uint8list);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Image>(
      future: generateThumbnail(widget.videoName),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("${widget.videoName}"),
            trailing: snapshot.data,
          );
        } else {
          return Text("No image can be generated");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            VideoSelectPageListTile(
              videoName: "test",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I guess this worked out of the box in the original example because ImagePicker handles permissions for us somehow. Very good. Thank you!!!